# How to get position of last clicked item in recycler view on focus changed in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, onfocuschangelistener

I have an issue, I need to get last clicked item position on focus change in recycler view in Kotlin.

For example: If my Recycler view contains 4 Edit text items. I entered a value on 2nd position. When I am clicking on last position, I need to get the position of 2nd Item. But the issue now is, when I am clicking on last position, which is 4th, I am getting that position on focus change only. Please find the below code of mine.

```
itemBinding.root.itemCount.setOnFocusChangeListener {
  view,
  hasfocus ->
  if (hasfocus) {
    if (hasfocus && isTouched && (selectedPosition != position)) {
      isTouched = false
      itemBinding.scan.performClick()
    }
  }
  if (!ignoreUpdate && isFrom == "countScreen") {
    updateCountItem(itemResponse, selectedPosition, false)
  }
}

itemBinding.root.itemCount.setOnTouchListener {
  view,
  motionEvent ->
  mRecyclerView!!.post {
    selectedPosition = adapterPosition
    listener.onFocusChange(layoutPosition, "countScreen")
  }
  false
}

private fun updateCountItem(itemResponse: ScanItemModel, position: Int, isCount: Boolean) {
  ignoreUpdate = true
  selectedPosition = position
  itemBinding.root.itemCount.selectAll()
  isTouched = true

  if (!itemDetailBinding.root.itemCount.text.toString().equals("")) {
    var a = 0
    var b = 0
    if (itemBinding.itemCount.text.toString().equals("")) {
      a = 0
    } else {
      a = itemBinding.itemCount.text.toString().toInt()
    }
    if (itemResponse.total != null) {
      if (itemResponse.total!! >= 0) {
        b = itemResponse.total!!
      } else {
        b = 0
      }
    }
    val sum = a.plus(b)
    if (sum < 3) {
      if (itemResponse.total != null) {
        itemResponse.total = sum
      } else {
        itemResponse.total = sum
      }

      itemBinding.root.totalCount.setText(itemResponse.total.toString())
      isOnBind = true
      listener.quantityChanged(
        position,
        itemResponse
      )
      isOnBind = false

      itemBinding.root.itemCount.text.clear()
      ignoreUpdate = false
    } else {
      if (itemResponse.total != null) {
        itemResponse.total = sum
      } else {
        itemResponse.total = sum
      }

      itemBinding.root.itemCount.setText(scanItemResponse.total.toString())
      isOnBind = true
      listener.countQuantityChanged(
        position,
        itemResponse
      )
      isOnBind = false

      itemBinding.root.itemCount.text.clear()
      ignoreUpdate = false
    }
  } else {
    ignoreUpdate = false
  }
}
```

Comment: save the postion when clicks

Answer (score 0):

```
class RvAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter....... {
  var itemClicked: Int ? = -1

  fun onItemClikcedPosition(pos: Int) {

    when(pos) {

      1 -> {
        println("previous clicked item $itemClicked")
        itemClicked = pos
      }

      2 -> {
          println("previous clicked item $itemClicked")
          itemClicked = pos
        }
        .....and so on........
    }
  }
}
```